# Future not working properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, fibers

```
const Future = require('fibers/future')
function myfunc() {
    var future = new Future();
    Eos().getInfo((err, res) => {
        future["return"]=res;
    })
    return future.wait();
};
console.log(myfunc());
```

The Error is can't wait without a fiber please help me with this

Comment: Can you try this? 
var fn = async function() {
  Eos().getInfo((err, res) => {
        return res;
    })
}.future();
var future = await fn();
future.wait();

Comment: `future.return` is a function, so you should call it, not overwrite it (`future.return(res);`). In the recent versions of JS, promises and async/await are easier to use, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of this with promises.

```
function myfunc() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        Eos().getInfo((err, res) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            }
            else {
                resolve(res);
            }
        });
    });
}
myfunc()
    .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error states a future can only "wait" if it is ran within a fiber

```
console.log(Fiber(myfunc).run());
```

Comment: it is giving me undefined

Comment: @yashvadhvani because your original function doesn't return any value you need to `future.return("some value")`